# Setting up a new stream for warc bolt fails

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I'm trying to setup a new stream to connect a Tika bolt to a warc bolt.

```
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt;
import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.warc.WARCHdfsBolt;

builder.setBolt("tika", new ParserBolt(), numWorkers)
  .localOrShuffleGrouping("shunt","tika");

WARCHdfsBolt warcbolt = getWarcBolt("XX");

builder.setBolt("warc", warcbolt, numWorkers)
  .localOrShuffleGrouping("tika",  "warc");
```

In the Tika definition I have modified the outputDeclarerFields function as follows to define my new "warc" stream:

```
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
  declarer.declare(new Fields("url", "content", "metadata", "text"));
  declarer.declareStream(StatusStreamName, new Fields("url", "metadata", "status"));
  declarer.declareStream("warc",   new Fields("url", "content", "metadata", "text"));
}
```

However, when I launch the topology in local mode I get:

> 14308 [main] WARN  o.a.s.d.s.Slot - SLOT debian8:1027 Starting in
>   state EMPTY - assignment null 14308 [main] WARN  o.a.s.d.s.Slot - SLOT
>   debian8:1028 Starting in state EMPTY - assignment null 14308 [main]
>   WARN  o.a.s.d.s.Slot - SLOT debian8:1029 Starting in state EMPTY -
>   assignment null 14309 [main] INFO  o.a.s.l.AsyncLocalizer - Cleaning
>   up unused topologies in
>   /tmp/a1e3b7f5-e251-40ae-a032-b0839ca103c8/supervisor/stormdist 14318
>   [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.Supervisor - Starting supervisor with id
>   f42c64cd-7c36-40ab-9f85-4b7751ed2d6a at host debian8. 15030 [main]
>   WARN  o.a.s.d.nimbus - Topology submission exception. (topology
>   name='xxCrawler') #error {  :cause nil  :via  [{:type
>   org.apache.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException    :message nil
>   :at [org.apache.storm.daemon.common$validate_structure_BANG_ invoke
>   common.clj 185]}]  :trace 
>   [[org.apache.storm.daemon.common$validate_structure_BANG_ invoke
>   common.clj 185]
>   [org.apache.storm.daemon.common$system_topology_BANG_ invoke
>   common.clj 378]
>   [org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$mk_reified_nimbus$reify__10782
>   submitTopologyWithOpts nimbus.clj 1694]
>   [org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$mk_reified_nimbus$reify__10782
>   submitTopology nimbus.clj 1726]
>   [sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke0
>   NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java -2]
>   [sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
>   NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java 62]
>   [sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
>   DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java 43]   [java.lang.reflect.Method
>   invoke Method.java 498]   [clojure.lang.Reflector invokeMatchingMethod
>   Reflector.java 93]   [clojure.lang.Reflector invokeInstanceMethod
>   Reflector.java 28]   [org.apache.storm.testing$submit_local_topology
>   invoke testing.clj 310]
>   [org.apache.storm.LocalCluster$_submitTopology invoke LocalCluster.clj
>   49]   [org.apache.storm.LocalCluster submitTopology nil -1]
>   [com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology submit
>   ConfigurableTopology.java 76]
>   [com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology submit
>   ConfigurableTopology.java 65]   [xx.xx.xx.xx.xxTopology run
>   xxTopology.java 111]
>   [com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology start
>   ConfigurableTopology.java 50]   [xx.xx.xx.xx.xxTopology main
>   xxTopology.java 53]]} 15035 [main] ERROR
>   o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
>   org.apache.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException: null
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.common$validate_structure_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:185)
>   ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.common$system_topology_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:378)
>   ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$mk_reified_nimbus$reify__10782.submitTopologyWithOpts(nimbus.clj:1694)
>   ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$mk_reified_nimbus$reify__10782.submitTopology(nimbus.clj:1726)
>   ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
>   ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
>           at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
>   ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
>           at org.apache.storm.testing$submit_local_topology.invoke(testing.clj:310)
>   ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster$_submitTopology.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:49)
>   ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster.submitTopology(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>           at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology.submit(ConfigurableTopology.java:76)
>   ~[xx-crawler-1.1.jar:?]
>           at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology.submit(ConfigurableTopology.java:65)
>   ~[xx-1.1.jar:?]
>           at xx.xx.xx.xx.xxTopology.run(xxTopology.java:111) ~[xx-crawler-1.1.jar:?]
>           at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology.start(ConfigurableTopology.java:50)
>   ~[xx-crawler-1.1.jar:?]
>           at xx.xx.xx.xx.xxTopology.main(xxTopology.java:53) ~[xx-crawler-1.1.jar:?]

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Note that if I use the StatusStreamName ("status") stream to connect the tika and warc bolts it works fine.

Thank you,

Etienne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WARCs are generated from the raw, non-parsed content. You should connect the WARC to the output of the Fetcher instead of the Parser bolt.

You don't need to declare a new stream just for the warc, you could simply connect the warc bolt to the default stream coming out of the Tika bolt.

I see in your code

> import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt;

which would indicate that you are relying on the default implementation (which does not generate a 'warc' stream). Could you have forgotten to replace that with your modified implementation?

Comment: Dear Julien,

Thanks a lot for the helpful comments.

What I want is to archive to WARC files only selected web pages. The selection is based on a regex that sits in the parser. Then, if I have a match, archive the content of the page (using the "warc" stream). Hence the connection between the parser and the warc bolts.

Does this approach sound correct to you? Or should I go otherwise for implementing that?

Thank you again !

Etienne

Comment: Hi Etienne. Have edited my answer above. Had forgotten when I initially replied that the parser bolts also generate the binary content so you should not need to modify the tika bolt at all. You could write a bespoke bolt to check the content of the metadata and pass on only the tuples that have a K/V that you'd have set during the parsing.
If you deal only with HTML pages, then stick to the JsoupParser bolt.
BTW was the initial problem due to an incorrect import. If so please mark my answer as correct. Thanks!